# pip not finding packages from pypi.python.org

Tags: macos, python, pip

I'm running pip v1.5.6 that comes with python installed via homebrew, on OSX 10.11

When running `pip install emo` for example, I get:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement emo
```

**pip.log** reads:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Mon Jan  5 11:50:28 2015
Downloading/unpacking emo
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/emo/
  URLs to search for versions for emo:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/emo/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/emo/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement emo
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/v0/jsnj03_s7kvcf6xt32s_bt_40000gn/T/pip_build_elzi...
No distributions at all found for emo
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for emo
```

https://pypi.python.org/simple/emo takes a very long time to load for me but does in fact exist.

Any idea what could be happening? Other packages, for example "scapy", install fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `emo` package does not actually exist - see the [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/emo) page for details. Its status is "Planning", meaning that someone registered the package name, but hasn't actually developed the package yet.

Comment: Where can I see this? `emo` is a trending github repo so that seems so unlikely. I get this error with a lot of other packages.

Comment: @elzi you can use `pip` to install from a github repo - see [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#vcs-support) for info. Alternatively, you can clone the repo, then run `python setup.py install` inside it.